# Paginating a slice

Tags: go

What's the best way to paginate over a slice in Go and avoid errors like `panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range`

For example, if I have a slice like

```
slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

and I call

```
slice[6:10]
```

I get a panic error.

I came up with this:

```
func paginate(x []int, skip int, size int) []int {
  limit := func() int {
    if skip+size > len(x) {
      return len(x)
    } else {
      return skip + size
    }

  }

  start := func() int {
    if skip > len(x) {
      return len(x)
    } else {
      return skip
    }

  }
  return x[start():limit()]
}
```

[link to playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xmBwUMwE41)

Are there better ways to do this in Go?

Thanks

Comment: You could use the math package's Min func as well. And I wouldn't bother defining and calling inner funcs just set the values directly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, while there is no nice way to do it, I think it would be cleaner if you used variables instead of functions. It also looks cleaner when you remove the else clause.

```
func paginate(x []int, skip int, size int) []int {
    if skip > len(x) {
        skip = len(x)
    }

    end := skip + size
    if end > len(x) {
        end = len(x)
    }

    return x[skip:end]
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Why limit to a certain slice type?

```
func Paginate(pageNum int, pageSize int, sliceLength int) (int, int) {
    start := pageNum * pageSize

    if start > sliceLength {
        start = sliceLength
    }

    end := start + pageSize
    if end > sliceLength {
        end = sliceLength
    }

    return start, end
}
```

```
    start, end := Paginate(pageNum, pageSize, len(someSlice))
    pagedSlice := someSlice[start:end]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be?   **start := (pageNum-1) * pageSize**

Answer (score 2):

I just found [go-linq](https://github.com/ahmetalpbalkan/go-linq), which is inspired by Microsoft Linq

To paginate, like in the question I posted, you would write:

```
From(x).Skip(0).Take(10)
```

And you will get the expected result. This library takes care of returning an empty slice if your `Skip` and/or `Take` values would otherwise result in an out of range error.